# why using internal status flag ? C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, flags

In the following code ,I don't know the target of using internal status flag : (C#)

```
// internal status flag
    private int status = 0;

    // status constants
    private const int AMOUNT_SET = 1;
    private const int RATE_SET = 2;
    private const int PERIODS_SET = 4;
    private const int ALL_SET = AMOUNT_SET | RATE_SET | PERIODS_SET;
public double LoanAmount
        {
            get
            {
                return this.loanAmount;
            }
            set
            {
                this.loanAmount = Math.Abs(value); //taking the absolute value of the user input to ensure getting  positive values
                this.status |= AMOUNT_SET;
                CalcPayment(); //check if the method can calculate yet 
            }
        }

 public double InterestRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.interestRate;
            }
            set
            {
                this.interestRate = Math.Abs(value);
                if (this.interestRate >= 1)
                    this.interestRate /= 100;    // if entered as a percent, convert to a decimal
                this.status |= RATE_SET;
                CalcPayment();
            }
        }

        public int Periods
        {
            get
            {
                return this.periods;
            }
            set
            {
                this.periods = Math.Max(Math.Abs(value), 1);
                this.status |= PERIODS_SET;
                CalcPayment();
            }
        }

        public double MonthlyPayment
        {
            get
            {
                return this.monthlyPayment;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n\tThis is a loan of " + this.loanAmount.ToString("c") + " at " + this.interestRate.ToString("p") +
                    " interest for " + this.periods.ToString() + " months,\n\t\twith a monthly payment of " +
                    this.monthlyPayment.ToString("c") + ".";
        }

        private void CalcPayment()   
        {                              
            if (this.status == ALL_SET)
            {
                double periodicInterestRate = interestRate / 12;
                double compound = Math.Pow((1 + periodicInterestRate), periods);
                this.monthlyPayment = this.loanAmount * periodicInterestRate * compound /                   (compound - 1);
            }
        }
```

So why did it use status flag ? 
Thanks

Comment: This looks like someone just trying to use a "technical but not necessary" solution (Hey look at me! I can use flags!) Using booleans or, my preference: nullable values as property types, would have worked just as well.

Comment: I would have at least used a more standardized way of doing this.. such as an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a clever way of making sure that all the required functions have been called.

Initially, the status flag as an int looks like this in binary:

```
0000  // truncated for clarity it would really be 32 0's
```

once the amount is set, the flag looks like this:

```
0001
```

Once rate is set, it looks like

```
0011 // because 2 in binary is ...0010, so ORing 0001 and 0010 -> 0011
```

Comment: Thak you so much ,but I'm wondering what would we miss if didn't use that flag ?Like what kind of weakness the code will be ?

Comment: You'll get an incorrect answer. I don't know why it was designed like that, but basically every time a property is set, it will attempt to calculate the payment. Obviously, if one of the values isn't set yet, it will still be 0, and you get an incorrect calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the original intent was that the calculation was only done if all fields are set. The flag is important because double and int are both value types that have a default value of 0.0d and 0 respectively.

I can see this being done before C# had Nullable struct or the short cut T? where included in the language.

Comment: That is right ,I'm taking an introduction to object oriented class ,very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that it is `easier` to use

```
 if (this.status == ALL_SET)
```

then having 3 nullable and doing (pseudo kind of code)

```
 if (this.LoanAmount.HasValue && this.InterestRate.HasValue && this.Periods.HasValue)
```

code preference i think

Comment: just keep in mind that calling this.LoanAmount.HasValue etc. only works on nullable types